# Javascript : Determine duplicate objects in an array and return array of them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects

```
[
 {
    classname: ".icon"
    data : "12"
    },
    {
    classname: ".icon1"
    data : "34"
    },
    {
    classname: ".icon2"
    data : "56"
    },
    {
    classname: ".icon"
    data : "78"
    },
    {
    classname: ".icon1"
    data : "90"
    },
    {
    classname: ".icon1"
    data : "AB"
    }
]
```

I want to return an array of array grouped by their duplication, like this

```
[
{
classname: ".icon"
data : "12"
},
{
classname: ".icon"
data : "78"
}
]

[
{
classname: ".icon1"
data : "34"
},
{
classname: ".icon1"
data : "90"
},
{
classname: ".icon1"
data : "AB"
}
]
```

I can use lodash as well as native JavaScript.
**Important**: The order of their original occurrence must be maintained in the returned array of array.
I am keying on the property name 'classname'

Comment: Embarrassing attempts at map reduce and lodash _uniq. There's plenty of code about the remove duplicate, but not return based on a key value

Comment: how many points is your project worth?

Comment: did you try to, instead of the "remove" logic in those examples, to save those who are duplicate and return them in an array? because... like... that should work boet

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `reduce()`

```js
var data = [{"classname":".icon","data":"12"},{"classname":".icon1","data":"34"},{"classname":".icon2","data":"56"},{"classname":".icon","data":"78"},{"classname":".icon1","data":"90"},{"classname":".icon1","data":"AB"}]

var obj = {}
var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!obj[e.classname]) {
    obj[e.classname] = []
    r.push(obj[e.classname])
  }
  obj[e.classname].push(e)
  return r;
}, [])


console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great :-)  My attempt was not far from yours but I'd missed off a logical condition. I've upped your answer